# copying settings

Tags: 3d-view, import, render-layers

As a newbie I'm probably clumsy with controls...

I have imported an OBJ several times, the first test was giving me a smooth surface, but I cannot remember how I got there and am unable to duplicate this and now all OBJ imports look like the second picture.

Can somebody explain what I have done and how to re-create this? The renderlayer has completely different settings (like use environment, AO, surfaces, hair), but I am unable to change that in the latter view.

Who has the experience to solve this?

Martin

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have switched from Cycles Render to Blender Render. This might have happened when you created a new file and the render engine was set back to the default. Try switching back to Cycles in a new file and importing again. If you have other issues, check the import settings to the lower left left of the file selection area.

I would personally recommend setting Cycles as the default render engine (if you use it more than Blender Render) by opening a new file, switching the engine to Cycles, then selecting File > Save Startup File to set Cycles as the default for all new files.